# How to get file-print to create output?

Tags: netlogo

I have created a setup button with the following code

```
to setup

  file-open "tcout.txt"

  file-print "Hello World" ;; File is in writing mode

end
```

and pressed it once. The file is created but it's empty:
[image]

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

In NetLogo, after writing output to a file you also have to close the file in the end:

either via `file-close` - closes the previously openend file

or via `file-close-all`- closes all previously opened files

Answer (score 2):

As in other languages, what happens when you write to a file (here, issue a `file-print` command) depends on your operating system.  If you want to ensure that what you are writing shows up immediately on disk, you need to flush or close the file.  Details are in the documentation:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-flush